# Remove default blur from input

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to remove the default blur from an input or a textarea element

```
<input type="text"/>
```

how I can do it with jquery ?

Comment: What do you mean by `remove the default blur`

Comment: Try with: `$("input").off('blur');`

Comment: There is no blurring on input, by default. Check what's up with your css

Comment: When focus on input, a blue color show is like a border of input or somthing like that..

Comment: @oscarvady not work [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVbJk/23/)

Comment: @SwarajGiri so what is called the blue thing when u focus on an input ?

Answer (score 5):

Try with this adding in your `CSS`

```
*:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: oscar is terse, but correct.  The issue is not a DOM event.  It is a styling issue that you can resolve by creating a cascading style (CSS class) that overrides the original style.  You can look for the original style using chrome's dev tools to inspect the element and then look for a :focus style applied to text inputs.  Then create your own class to override.